# "ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list", due to random numbers?

Tags: python, random

I'm writing a function to take a new card from a deck of cards, given that there are already some cards out of the deck.

```
def trekken(getrokken = []):
    import itertools
    import random

    getrokken = list(getrokken)
    kind = 'HCDS'
    value = '123456789XJQKA'
    deck = ["".join(card) for card in itertools.product(value,kind)]
    for i in range(0, len(getrokken)-1): deck.remove(getrokken[i])
    return(deck[(random.randint(1, len(deck)))])
```

When I use this for some examples a few times I sometimes get the error message:

```
 line 16, in trekken
    print(deck[(random.randint(1, len(deck)))])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

For example with the following input:

```
trekken(['6H', '3C', '3D', '8C', 'AD', '9D', '7D', 'QC'])
```

Maybe not the first time, but after a few tries (max. 20) I always get this error message.

Comment: random.randint(low, high) will also yield high, thus len(deck) might not be a good candidate for high, better choose a value smaller by one so try instead `return(deck[random.randint(0, len(deck)-1)])`. Note: The list index in Python starts at `0 ` not `1` as in other languages like `R`.

Comment: Why not just use `deck = ["".join(card) for card in itertools.product(value,kind) if ''.join(card) not in getrokken]`? Note that your `range()` will exclude the very last card from consideration.

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761

Comment: I get `IndexError: list index out of range` instead, because `random.randint()` **includes** the end point in consideration, so `len(deck)` is always a possibility. You are also not using the first card in the deck by starting at `1`. Use `return random.choice(deck)` instead.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: which is probably why they create a copy with `getrokken = list(getrokken)`. Not that the list is ever mutated.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I did that because the input could also be something like trekken({'4C', 'AH'})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python `random.randint(low, high)` will also yield `high`, thus `len(deck)` might not be a good candidate for high, better choose a value smaller by one so try instead as last line:

```
return deck[random.randint(0, len(deck)-1)]
```

Or even more clear - as @jonrsharpe suggests:

```
return deck[random.randrange(len(deck))]
```

... or as Martijn Pieters suggests:

```
return random.choice(deck)
```

Note: The list index in Python starts at `0` not `1` as in other languages like `R`.

Comment: Or just use `randrange(len(deck))`?

Comment: I suggest to follow the hints from Martijn and Jon comments also about the list literal etc ... ;-)